# Parsing NSString as JSON

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, json, parsing

I have read several forums but am seemingly unable to accomplish this simple task. I have a View in Xcode that points to a PHP script and stores the results as the NSString below:

[{"id":"16","name":"Bob","age":"37"}]

I am having trouble parsing this NSString. This is how I am getting the contents of the NSString:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/json.php?
id=%@",userId];

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

How do I convert the result (strResult) to JSON and take the objects out of it? I would assume its something like below, but I know I am missing something

```
NSString *name = [objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *age = [objectForKey:@"age"];
```

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: nothing to do with the xcode ide

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the class NSJSONSerialization to read it

```
id jsonData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //if input is NSString
id readJsonDictOrArrayDependingOnJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

---

in your case

```
NSArray *readJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *element1 = readJsonArray[0]; //old style: [readJsonArray objectAtIndex:0]
NSString *name = element1[@"name"]; //old style [element1 objectForKey:@"name"]
NSString *age = element1[@"age"]; //old style [element1 objectForKey:@"age"]
```

Comment: downvoter: sigh... what did I do today? :) [it's always a good Idea to leave a comment I'd say]

Comment: This IS the proper way to parse JSON, no clue why someone DV'd.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII thanks Richard, I will probably use this method. I am still trying to figure out where to place it though... Where would my NSString (strResult) go? would it replace (jsonString)?

Comment: yes, thats it... BUT you already have data so its even less work. I edited my code

Comment: @Daij-Djan no need to convert it back and forth to NSString and NSData.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Thanks all. Getting close here. On the NSDictionary *element1 line I am getting the following error "Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'"

Comment: oh older xcode / compiler? I use features from 4.5+, I edited the code but you should REALLY update

Comment: hmm. I'm on 4.4.1... maybe thats the issue. I will upgrade this weekend. Thank you! ill test it out

Comment: for now, use the //old style lines

Comment: @Daij-Djan, you are awesome... and so is Stackoverflow... Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Try this....

```
NSString * strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseMutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
SBJSON *jsonParser = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
if([[jsonParser objectWithString:strResult] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSArray *jsonArr=[jsonParser objectWithString: strResult];
    NSDictionary *firstDictonary = [jsonArr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *name = [firstDictonary valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *age = [firstDictonary valueForKey:@"age"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting for iOS 5 and higher just use NSJSONSerialization

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If you are targeting lower than iOS 5, use a JSON parser like this one: http://stig.github.com/json-framework/

And just call JSONValue (or equivalent) method on your JSON string:

```
NSDictionary *dict= [strResult JSONValue];

NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *age = [dict objectForKey:@"age"];
```

By the way, your JSON string looks like an array, and you can not use `objectForKey` to get objects from an `NSArray`. You have two options, modify your JSON string response as a dictionary or use `objectAtIndex` to get objects.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization nowadays -- only fallback to this if you need to support ios4 and below

Comment: Thanks @Daij-Djan, I will try looking at NSJSONSerialization. I am programming for iOS 5, so that should work right?