# get title and images for event using webservice xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, string, parsing

As the title said, i tried to get title name and image using webservice so i can dynamically change it via MySQL Database.
Here is the webservice result:

```
{"event":[{"event_id":"1","title":"grand meeting","logo":"grandmeeting.png"}],"succeed":1}
```

and Here is my view controller IBOutlet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageText;
```

Here is my code to grab the webservice

```
NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/service.php"];
NSData *dataURL=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strResult=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now my problem is i dont have any idea how to parse the strResult into title and image.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: here you go… http://stackoverflow.com/a/13665054/1042240

Comment: i tried but it sent uncaught exception said that 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized bla bla bla..'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSError *err;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/service.php"]];
NSData *dataFromUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options:         NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSJSONSerialization *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options:     NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSMutableDictionary *dataDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonData];
NSString *titleStr = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"event"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey: @"title"];
NSString *imageNameStr = [[[dataDict valueForKey:@"event"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey: @"logo"];
```

If you want to show this image from url in an image view just place this code

```
[ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:// your web address /%@",imageNameStr]]]];
```

Comment: i tried your code but it throw this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9d4e570'

Comment: just a minite i did not see the array i am editing my code again

Comment: It worked greatly as always Bhaskar. Thanks a lot for your great effort ^^ However, i tried to use your code for showing image and it said this error: -[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e57270

Comment: Sorry Bhaskar to bother again, i tried to use your code for showing image and it said this error: -[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e57270. I change the ImageView with my outlet which is _loginImage and its UIImageview *loginImage. Thank you

Comment: can you post your code for setting image or post the base url of this image example:
http://www.wallpaper.in.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Rose-Flower-Wallpaper-Free-Download2.jpg

Comment: I already figured out the problem Bhaskar. I should put NSURL function before put the NSString like this [ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:// your web address /%@",imageNameStr]]]]]; Thank you for your help. You're the best

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code to parse json data

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

NSMutableArray *array = dict[@"event"];
NSMutableDictionary *eventDict = [array objectAtIndex:0];


NSString *title = eventDict[@"title"];
NSString *logo = eventDict[@"logo"];
```